# Зацикливается PHP код

Tags: php, mysql

```
$clients_id = $_REQUEST['source_record'];
function getChild($pid){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE tasks.deleted = 0 AND tasks.parent_id = '".$pid."'";
        return $sql;
}

function getDB($sql){
    global $db;
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $tempArr = [];
    while($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($result)){
        $tempArr[$row['id']] = [];
    }

    return $tempArr;
}
function createArray($sid,$arr, &$tempArray){
        $sql = getChild($sid);
        $arr[$sid] = getDB($sql);
        array_push($tempArray, $sid);
        foreach ($arr[$sid] as $key => $value) {
            //Проверка ID а повторения во избежания зацикливания
            if(!in_array($key, $tempArray)){
                $arr[$sid] = createArray($key,$arr[$sid], $tempArray);
            }
        }
        return $arr;
}
//Временный массив для хранения Id и проверки на повторения
$tempArray = [];
$listId = [];
$listId = createArray($clients_id, $listId, $tempArray);
```

Есть ID записи $clients_id
Пустой массив который должен запонлится ID-шниками вложенных записей $listId

По идее на проверке
if(!in_array($key, $tempArray)){}
Он должен сверить текущий ID с уже записанными и если такой есть то не выполнять функцию но он всеравно зависает

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы мы, не имея доступа к вашему коду, проверили за вас, работает ли он так, как должен "по идее" или нет?

Comment: @Ипатьев, не, просто напиши код, он тебе задание скинет.

Comment: Я просто подумал может это какой-то глюк самого PHP о котором я не знаю.
Потому что новые ID проверку проходят, если ID повторяется то проверку он не проходит, но когда запускаю все вместе он зависает и у меня нет не каких идей почему.

Comment: Может кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным.

Comment: А ну вот помогло доагнал где ошибка.
тут все правльно рабоатет спс.

Comment: А как закрыть вопрос?